# Couldn't find file 'progress-bubble' with type 'text/css' after installing it by bower-rails in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bower

I got errors when I use progress-bubble in rails.

have installed 'bower-rails' in my project and it works well when i use bower install coverflow and sweetalert packages.

howerver, i use bower to install progress-bubble package today. when it was installed, i add //=require progress-bubble in application.js and *= require progress-bubble in application.css.sass, now i restart my server and visit my target view, i got "Couldn't find file 'progress-bubble' with type 'text/css'" error.

Here is the gist https://gist.github.com/skji/50163fb76a083d2de52f3872bce437cf.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: restart server first

Comment: @uzaif it didn't work.

Comment: how did you install bower dependencies?